# Not able to set environment variables inside a docker container when building image using gradle task

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, gradle

I have written a gradle task buildDocker in my build.gradle file as follows:

```
task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: copyJar) {
    push = false
    baseImage "openjdk:8u151"
    println System.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    println System.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    setEnvironment('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',System.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'))
    setEnvironment('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',System.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'))
    runCommand("mkdir myProject")
    addFile("myProject-0.0.jar","myProject/")
    workingDir("/myProject")
    runCommand("unzip -q myProject-0.0.jar")
    exposePort(8888)
    entryPoint(["java","-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions","- 
XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap","-XX:MaxRAMFraction=1","-XshowSettings:vm","-cp", 
"/myProject-config:.","org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"])
}
```

When I build the image by running the task I am able to see the println outputs in the terminal. But when I run the image, I keep getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMessageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/annotation/SqsConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@46244e65: profile file cannot be null]
```

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@46244e65: profile file cannot be null]
```

I have also tried setting the environment variables directly in the run statement by using the -e parameters in the run command and by mounting my ~/.aws/credentials file to the docker container , but with those also, I get the same exception.

EDIT1: here's the docker run command using the -e flags :

```
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXX --link mysql --name myapp <imageName>
```

Also, put the credentials as key value pairs in a file-env.list and tried this:

```
docker run --env-file env.list -v --link mysql --name myapp <imagename>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working with mounting my credentials file to the docker container:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws --link mysql --name myapp <imageName>
```

the credentials are created and stored in the .aws folder. The mistake I was doing earlier, with mounting was a stupid one, probably because of fatigue, I kept mounting it on the /home directory in the container but home folder (~) in the container is /root instead, so once I changed that , there weren't any issues.Though  I still don't understand why the -e flags are not working, as according to this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html the amazon java sdk will try to load the credentials from the env variables first and then from the java system properties and then from the default credential profiles file.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables that are defined in scripts that run when building an image, are not kept when creating a container based on that image.

You need to explicitly set environment variables using `ENV` directive in your Dockerfile, or set them when running the container using the `-e` flag, for example.

Please see [this article](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-vs-env/) for more information.

Comment: I tried setting the env variables using the -e flag in the run command too, but I still get the same exception.

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect how you tried to use the -e flag?